# Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth issues

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I have an issue with my Bluetooth for some time now.
I have Bluetooth headphones, they work just fine with all of my other devices, but for some reason, they're killing me when using ubuntu.
If I pair them, and then take them off, every website/program that uses audio is getting stuck, including YouTube (showing a "loading" animation), and once I turned off the headphones or shutting down the Bluetooth service - everything magically works!
The only solution right now is to turn off the Bluetooth service and re-pair the headphones.

EDIT:

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
    [8086:06f0] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc.  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:9106 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8152 Fast Ethernet Adapter 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0801 Terminus Technology Inc.  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've searched everywhere on the web, no solution has been found.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command. It is a very obvious problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot. That should solve the problem.

The setting can be reverted by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

But the really good solution is to use 5 GHz Wi-Fi.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep you updated once I know it solves the issue. by the way, what was the issue?

Comment: The problem is with sharing 2.4 GHz for BT and Wi-Fi.

Comment: It did not fix the issue. What should I do next?

Comment: Switch Wi-Fi to 5GHz.

Comment: I think the problem might be different, as I said, I am able to use both WIFI and Bluetooth at the same time, until I'm stopping a song or removing my headset for a moment (they're pausing the song because of that), so if I understood correctly, Only one of them supposed to work at the same time from the beginning